# Click event on every item on populated list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here is how I populate my list:

```
function bingNetworksList(myList) {
    var list = '';
    for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
      list += '<li><a href="#">' + myList[i] + '</a></li>';
    }

    $('#myList').empty();
    $('#myList').append(list);
}
```

Here is my html file:

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

I want to add a click event for every item of list (without having separate ids):

```
$(function() {
  $('#myList').click(function() {
    var listItem = this.find('a').text();
    console.log(listItem); // never logged
  });
});
```

**However, when I click at a list item, click event doesn't fire.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you make jsfiddle so other can help you quickly

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume there's a js error in your console.

I've created a working sample for you. We can use event delegation and then retrieve the DOM node that was clicked. You need to ensure you call the bingNetworksList [assume typo in here and meant binD ;)] function when the DOM ready event has fired.

```
function bingNetworksList(myList) {
    var list = '';
    for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
      list += '<li><a href="#">' + myList[i] + '</a></li>';
    }

    $('#myList').empty();
    $('#myList').append(list);
}

$(function() {
  var list = ["foo", "bar"]
  bingNetworksList(list);
  $('#myList').click(function(evt) {
    var listItem = $(evt.target).text();
    console.log(listItem); // never logged
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `this` inside `$` as  like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myList').click(function() {
    var listItem = $(this).find('a').text();
    console.log(listItem); // will always be logged
  });
});
```

Comment: That will find all the a nodes, not the one that was clicked.

Comment: @CainBot I am aware of that. Not mentioned in question.

Comment: despite the name, I did suspect you were aware of this, was more for OPs benefit =)